# Gerund or other grammatical construction?

Tags: grammar, gerunds

I am not able to figure out why there is a gerund in this sentence:

> My mother *convinced* me to sing, without me initially **wanting** to.

Could someone explain why there is a gerund?
Is it a some kind of grammatical construction?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: _wanting_ is the gerund participle here.

Comment: There isn't one, and in any case it doesn't matter. Traditional grammar analyses "wanting" in your example as a present participle. Modern grammar doesn't distinguish gerunds and present participles, calling the _ing_ forms simply 'gerund-participles'. The most important thing is that "wanting" is a verb, which here is functioning as predicator in the non-finite clause "me initially wanting to". We know it's not a noun because it is modified by the adverb "initially", and adverbs can't (normally) modify nouns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> There isn't one, and in any case it doesn't matter. Traditional grammar analyses "wanting" in your example as a present participle. Modern grammar doesn't distinguish gerunds and present participles, calling the *ing* forms simply 'gerund-participles'. The most important thing is that "wanting" is a verb, which here is functioning as predicator in the non-finite clause "me initially wanting to". We know it's not a noun because it is modified by the adverb "initially", and adverbs can't (normally) modify nouns.